# Add acrobat javascript to pdf documents in ruby or python

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, pdf

I want to add some Acrobat JavaScript to a pdf file. I have seen some answers which suggest using [iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209972/how-to-programmatically-inject-javascript-in-pdf-files) but I am looking for a solution in either ruby or python. I looked at the [HexaPdf](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/) but could not find any mention of Javascript.

Comment: What you are looking for is a library that either supports the "Additional Actions" property of fields or will allow you to create arbitrary COS dictionaries so you can add AAs the brute force way. I don't see that capability in HexaPDF. In my experience, you'll find that the PDF tools that are Java or C++ based tend to be more comprehensive than anything in ruby or python.

Comment: @joelgeraci can you please suggest a C++ tool?

Comment: The Adobe PDF Library, is a C++ library available through Datalogics is a library capable of creating COS dictionaries that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), which is a JAVA based pdf library.